# how to use loop to subset 1000 csv files and do co-integration test in R?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

data looks like [sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y70zC.png)
[sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73hRM.png)

I have 1000 csv files, all of them have two columns, first column is `date`, second column is `price`. Files have different time periods, some data start from 1995, some data start from 2000,since I need to do co integration test, all data in test should have exactly same time point.

I need extract same time period from 1000 csv files, for example start from 1998-4-20.

It works if I do it individually using:

```r
newdata208 <- subset(data208, Date >= "1998-04-20")
```

but when I try to loop them, error happen, could anyone help me fixed error?

```r
v1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  v1[i] <- subset(datasets[i], Date >= "1998-04-20")
}
```

> Error in subset.default(datasets[i], Date >= "1998-04-20") :
> object 'Date' not found

#### for original problem, just add get(i) in loop, then problem is fixed, I do not why, could anyone tell me?

```r
v1 <- list()
for (i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  data <- get(i)
  v1[i] <- subset(data, Date >= "1998-04-20")}
```

then, problem is fixed

#### updating my stupid code

```r
#set dictionary.
setwd("F:/xxx/folder")

dataset <- list.files(pattern = "*.CSV")
datasets <- c()
 
for (i in 1:1000)) {
  datasets[i] <- substr(dataset[i], 1, (nchar(dataset[i])-4))
}

# we only need closing price column and date column
setClass("myDate")
setAs("character", "myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))

# read date column and closing price column
for (i in 1:length(temps)) {
 
 assign(temps[i], read.csv(temp[i], 
        colClass = c("myDate", rep("NULL", 4), 
        rowClass = "numeric", 
        rep("NULL", 2)), stringsAsFactor = FALSE, header = TRUE))
}
 
# extract same time period
v1 <- c()
for (i in temps) { 
  data <- get(i)
  v1[i] <- subset(data, Date >= "1998-04-20", select = C)
}

# lengths are different, file505 has short time period
index <- subset(file505, Date >= "1998-04-20")
indexs <- index$Date

# try use index to extract data 
selectdate <- which(file001$Date %in% indexs)
file001CLOSE <- file001[selectdate, "C"]

#redo loop to get same period
v2 <- c()
for (i in datasets) { 
  data2 <- get(i)
  v2[[i]] <- data2[selectdate, "C"]
}

v2table <- do.call(cbind,v2)

# right now, data is wonderful, let's begin do time series.
# test co-integration
install.packages("urca")
library("urca")

comb <- combn(1000, 2)
 
pairs <- c()
for (i in 1:499500) { 
  pairs[[i]] <- v2table[, comb[, i]]
}

# test:FF <- pairs[[88]], it is working wonderful, display all details in   result
# do ca.jo 

testresults <- list()
for (i in 1:499500) {
  testdata <- pairs[[i]]
  testresults[[i]] <- ca.jo(testdata, ecdet = "const", type = "eigen", K = 1)
}
```

it creates a huge list containing all test results, I need to split Values of teststatistic and critical values of test, and find all pairs have co-integration factor.

Comment: it seems to me like one of the csv files is missing the `Date` column

Comment: no, if I try do small sample 10 files, the loop is still not work, I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

I've got a two step solution for you:

```
x <- list.files(path = "your directory", pattern = ".csv")
y <- lapply(x,fread)
data <- rbindlist(y)
```

Reads in all the csvs in your directory as data tables then binds then together.

After that i'd just subset as follows:

```
data <- data[Date >= "your dates",]
```

EDIT*

I get the feeling you want to bring in your data and bind it column wise/merge. As it stands that would be incorrect as you have the same "C" value in each column. After looking at your samples, if you were to stack those row wise you'd just be getting a very long C column. I wonder whether each C column represents the same or a different variable. If it is a different variable, I've written up some code which would truncate your data appropriately.

I've used the first **6 rows** of your sample data 1 and sample data 2

```
    files <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = ".csv")

data_mock <- lapply(files,fread)

data_mock[[1]][, Date := data_mock[[2]][,Date]] 
#I change the dates here because your sample dates are too far apart to test for date truncation to work

for (i in 1:length(data_mock)){
  data_mock[[i]]$Date <- as.Date(data_mock[[i]]$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
}

for (i in 1:length(data_mock)){
  setnames(data_mock[[i]], old = names(data_mock[[i]]), new = c("Date", paste0("C",i)))
}
#I change the variable names here because I'm not sure whether you want to stack Cs ontop of one another or whether each C is a different variable.
#I've assumed each C is different.

start_finish <- function(data, start, finish){
  data[Date >= start & Date <= finish,]
}

results <- list()
for (i in 1:length(data_mock)){
results[[i]] <- start_finish(data_mock[[i]], "1987-01-15", "1987-01-17")
}
```

This is what the original data looked like:

```
    [[1]]
         Date      C
1: 1998-04-20 12.667
2: 1998-04-21 12.587
3: 1998-04-22 12.625
4: 1998-04-23 12.601
5: 1998-04-24 12.584
6: 1998-04-25 12.624

[[2]]
         Date     C
1: 1987-01-14 95.89
2: 1987-01-15 97.72
3: 1987-01-16 98.10
4: 1987-01-17 97.07
5: 1987-01-18 98.86
6: 1987-01-19 99.95
```

This is what it looks like once you run a loop over the "start_finish" function I wrote:

```
[[1]]
         Date      C
1: 1987-01-15 12.587
2: 1987-01-16 12.625
3: 1987-01-17 12.601

[[2]]
         Date    C2
1: 1987-01-15 97.72
2: 1987-01-16 98.10
3: 1987-01-17 97.07
```

I believe you wanted your data to start and end at the same time? You merely need to alter the "start" and "finish" dates in the pretty simple function I wrote.

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I did it before like you did, the problem is that I need to do a co-integration test,this test need a table which each column has same length, if I did rbind to form a large column , I do not know how to separate them to 1000 column.

Comment: I don't quite follow, would you be able to show me what your data looks like? Maybe do head("your data", n = 10).  Or maybe show me what happens once you run the code I suggested, then make a mock data table of what you'd like to see.

Secondly, what are you testing co-integration on if you've only got a price variable...price is co-integrated with what?

Comment: please click sample data in front of page, I just edit it, this problem is a time series problem, first of all, I have 1000 data, I need to to co-integration each of them, means 2C1000,R has combination function could deal it, but each of them need have same length, if data start same period like 1998-04-20, it is wonderful, I could apply head(n= some numbers) but all datas have different starting point, supervisor said please extract a period from 1998-04-20 to 2005-05-15 something like that, then do co-integration test all of them. first of all, I must extract 1000 files to same time period.

Comment: hi,Gin, just add one sentence, get(i), then everything is wonderful, I would post codes later..

Comment: hi,Gin, the aim for this project is to learn data manipulation, I have 1000 csv files in my usb drive,all of them is small size,it is not hard do them one by one, but is so boring,meanwhile,data is incomplete, they have different time period, but they have one intersection interval,even though in same period, some information in someday is missing, I can not allow add missing data from internet, just find overlap part. I use %in% to deal with that, you could check it if you like, and I have use loop to finish 2C1000 co-integration test, but it is a big list, I need split that right now.